# How can I achieve curly or wavy borders for a view on Android?

Tags: android, layout

There is the concept of rounded corners for views and drawables in Android, however, am working on an interface for a kids robot, and someone asked for curly borders - sort of like wavy (sine wave kind of thing). Now, how the heck can one achieve such a thing in either XML or Java - especially, without resorting to use of image overlays or backgrounds?

Answer (score 1):

rounded corners aren't in fact rounded `View`s, its just a bit of transparency in corners. you can create some custom `drawable`s/`Bitmap`s and set for your `View`s (as a background or use `ImageView`) or you can use custom programmatic drawing like [HERE](https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/custom-drawing)

Answer (score 0):

Have tried to use images of that form and use them as background in a transparent container?

Comment: See my note about not wanting to use image overlays or backgrounds. If you can demo with some code, would also help.